# Graphql best pratice: several queries at once or array argument

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am facing a small design decision on a graphql project.

The schema is:

```
type Foo {
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  getFoo(id: ID):Foo
}
```

Retrieving several Foo is quite verbose:

```
query {
  A : getFoo(id:1) {
    id
  }
  B : getFoo(id:2) {
    id
  }
  ...
}
```

I was considering updating the schema to:

```
type Foo {
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  getFoo(input: [ID]):[Foo]
}
```

This would help having less verbose and lighter requests if there is more than object queried, however it requires implementation server side.

Which of the two option is the good approach? The difference is very light, but as I am only starting with graphql I would like to pick up the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I finally opted to keep the original schema

```
type Foo {
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  getFoo(id: ID):Foo
}
```

My main reasons are :

- Semantically correct
- Gives more freedom to the client
- Input validation easier to implement on atomic queries
- Each query needs a database transaction to be resolved. Failing to mutate database data would result in the whole transaction rollback. Depending on your needs you might want this.